# C#: UserManager.FindAsync always finds a match

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

`UserManager.FindAsync` always finds a match even when I input a wrong username and password it always returns with some sort of userID.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Mobilelogin(LoginViewModel model)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
    if (user != null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(201); // user found
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401); // user not found
    }
}
```

Comment: `FindAsync` returns a task. You need to wait on the task asynchronously to get the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FindAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497605(v=vs.108).aspx) returns a `Task<TUser>`. If you work with it synchronously (as you are doing right now), you will always get the `Task` itself which is not null.

You need to wait on the task asynchronously to get the result (the `TUser`) like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Mobilelogin(LoginViewModel model)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
    if (user != null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(201); // user found
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401); // user not found
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this reference](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) for more information about asynchronous programming with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that :) Thanks!